# Is it customary to bring gifts to an upsherin?

Tags: gifts, upsherin

Do people generally bring gifts to an upsherin of a friend's son?

If so, what sort of gifts are appropriate?

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/upsherin-gift

Comment: It may help to specify kind of Jew you friend is. Observance, association, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my experiencing of both giving and receiving, regular birthday presents for a three year old boy are the norm. Only grandparents or great uncles seem tempted to give religious items like an aleph bina or Yarmulka.

Comment: You know, I was expecting @YeZ to ask how i remember what I received for my upsherin when I was three years old.